# Unable to enable VS 2019 Live Visual Tree. No option for "Enable UI Debugging Tools"

Tags: visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-debugging

I wanted to use the Visual Studio 2019 (version 16.8.3) "Live Visual Tree today" in my WPF application.   So I went into Tools >> Options >> Debug >> General and was surprised to discover that there was no checkbox for "Enable UI Debugging Tools" or anything like that.  I know it used to be there.  Now it's not.

I went through all the other Debug options and could see no similar option anywhere.

And when I debug now, although I can bring up the "Live Visual Tree" window, it tells me that "UI Debugging is either disabled, not supported by the current application, or the application execution is paused".

I do this when it is *not* paused, if that matters.  My app is .NET 5.0 using WPF in C#.

So what happened to the Live Visual Tree?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The option on VS2019 is under **Tools**-->**Options**-->**Debugging**-->**Hot Reload** rather than **Tools** --> **Options** --> **Debug** --> **General**.

**Then**, check **WPF** option under **Enable XAML Hot Reload**.

[image]

Comment: Thank you.  I saw the bit about "enable just my xaml in live visual tree" but I didn't realize that hot reload actually turned on/off the visual tree.

Comment: A small cosmetic difference with the 2022 version of Visual Studio, but basically the same:                                                                                                                              
The WPF option in VS2022 is under Tools-->Options-->Debugging-->XAML Hot Reload